# BrowserSync notify false not working in gulp

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I have following in my gulp file to turn off the browser notification but it still shows up:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app',
    },
    notify: false
  })
});
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: What happens if you leave it out completely?

Answer (score 0):

For those getting in the same situation, since it automated and reloads anything I thought it reloads the gulp watch as well.

So I rerun the gulp watch and now its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you fixed this problem already but you have no result becouse you should to rerun browser-sync